# Spring boot and React js Paypal Rest api payment gateway

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest, paypal

Please help me to integrate paypal payment gateway using rest api. I used react js as frontend. Spring boot as backend. Need to implement validate payment by paypal rest sdk from backend side

Implementation rest api papal payment gateway with react and spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Looking thru i was able to see this https://www.baeldung.com/java-stripe-api

and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTm3hPzBRgg

Then this https://erpsolutions.oodles.io/developer-blogs/Integrating-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-Using-Spring-Boot/

And this is more explanatory https://attacomsian.com/blog/stripe-integration-with-spring-boot